# Convert Sql query to Lambda Expression - Filter Child Objects and Return Parent Objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

I found a post exactly my problem, but does not have a correct answer.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144919/using-lambda-select-where-or-linq-query-to-achieve-following-requirement/28646821#28646821)

*"I want filtered out" parent objects Which have children que meet the criteria. Parent shouldnt be returned only BUT Those children Which meet the criteria."*

Follows the sql query I want to convert lambda:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
RO
INNER JOIN
ROE
ON ROE.ROId = RO.Id
WHERE RO.TreeNode LIKE '.66.%' AND ROE.EnvironmentId = 3
```

I'm working entity framework. I have two entities: RO and ROE, follows entity struct:

```
public class RO 
{ 
     int ROId {get; set}
     string ROName {get; set}
     string TreeNode {get; set}
     EntityCollection<ROE> ROEs {get; set}
} 

public class ROE 
{ 
     int ROEId {get; set}
     int ROId {get; set}
     int environmentId {get; set}
     string ROName {get; set}
}
```

I want filtered RO objects which have TreeNode StartsWith '.66.' AND children meet criteria EnvironmentId = 3. But returns a List each RO haves filtered List.

I'm trying:

```
var ros = ROs.Where(ro => ro.TreeNode.StartsWith('.66.') && 
                       ro.ROEs.Any(roe => roe.EnvironmentId == environmentId))
```

But this expression don't working, because the ROEs Collection isn't filtered.

My question was answered. But my problem is the "Includes" because it does not work when I try to recover some child collections. For example:

```
var ros = context.ROS.Include("T").Include("T.TOEs").Include("ROEs.EL")
                     .Where(ro => ro.TreeNode.StartsWith('.66.'))
                     .Select(ro => new 
                                     {
                                       ro,
                                       // "T" Object is working, but the child collection "T.TOEs" isn't working
                                       T = ro.T,
                                       // "ROEs" Collection is working, but the child collection "ROEs.EL" isn't working
                                       ROEs = ro.ROEs.Where(roe => roe.EnvironmentId == environmentId)
                                     })
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(x => x.ro)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry. Now, I will use only "edit" link.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/861716) is what you mean.

Comment: @AdaltonVelosodeLima is your question answered?

Comment: My question was answered. But my problem is the "Includes" because it does not work when I try to recover some child collections.